# grouping two sites under domain and sub domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, url, forwarding, web

I have 2 websites a main website hosted at fasthosts and an e-commerce website hosted at Vidahost.

I want to combine both websites under the same domain set.

- Main site would be www.mydomain.com
- Store site would be shop.mydomain.com

I want to keep the directory path showing on the shop subdomain so what was previously www.mystore.com/product/hat would become shop.mydomain.com/product/hat

How can I accomplish this, have already created the subdomain on fasthosts and setup web forwarding to the store but the directory paths do not show.

Comment: What do you mean by "the directory paths do not show"? When you go to `shop.mydomain.com`, does it show exactly the same website/content as `www.mystore.com`? Does the URL change to `www.mystore.com/product/hat` when you click a hat product link? Please clarify

Comment: When I go to shop.mydomain.com it shows exactly the same content as www.mystore.com. However when I navigate through the store the URL is continously shop.mydomain.com. This means I can't link someone to a product. I would like to keep the beginning of the url as shop.mydomain.com but have it extended as shop.mydomain.com/products/hat. Hope this clarifies =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Fasthosts' Web Forwarding ***Masking*** option, they simply create a frame around the website you are "forwarding" to.

To accomplish your goal, you need to create a DNS CNAME record for `shop.mydomain.com` to point to `www.mystore.com`.

Before you do this, check out [this page at Vidahost' support site](https://www.vidahost.com/knowledge-base/support/how-to-add-an-addon-domain).

You'll probably need to add `shop.mydomain.com`, though it's not entirely clear what an "Addon Domain" is.

Chances are, they employ name based hosts, and when you try to access a site with a host header not configured at Vidahost, it won't work, so if the Addon Domain feature doesn't work, try contacting Vidahost support

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, I followed your instructions and shop.mydomain.com displays as www.myshop.com but when I navigate through the store. It reverts to www.myshop.com/.... I will try contacting vidahost as you suggested.